# Print None while comparing a list with the dataset in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, data-science

I have a dataset that includes noun, pronoun, proper noun and more. Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
در
همین
حال
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
نجیب
الله
خواجه
عمری
</coref>
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="np" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
سرپرست
وزارت
تحصیلات
عالی
افغانستان
</coref>
گفت
که
```

Now I want to check if a noun phrase is a pronoun. I compared the noun phrase with the possible list of pronouns in Dari. This feature should extract for both i_NP and j_NP. But I receive None as output. Here what I have tried.

```
PRONOUNS = ["او", "ما","تو", "شما", "وی", "ایشان",
"آنان", "آنها", "خود", "خویشتن", "خویش", "این",
"آن", "اینان", "اینها"]

def isPronoun_feature(text):
    coref = re.findall(r'<coref.*?>(.*?)</coref>', text, re.S)
    l = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), coref))
    for i in range(0,len(l)-1,2):
        i_NP =l[i]
        j_NP = l[i+1]
        #print(i_NP, j_NP)
        if i_NP in PRONOUNS:
            return True
        elif j_NP in PRONOUNS:
            return True
```

Comment: You don't return anything if the loop isn't entered.

Comment: Why? till print() part it give the result while it comes to the if condition does not print and I dont know the reason

Comment: Also, having `return` in a loop will break you out of the function on the first hit. Is this intended?

Comment: @user2988094 If you know the loop is entered, `i_NP in PRONOUNS` and `j_NP in PRONOUNS` must both be false, in which case nothing will be returned if the loop manages to end.

Comment: @roganjosh, yes, it is intended to return true if it is on the list.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, the comment # print(i_NP, j_NP) show me all the noun phrases in the dataset. but how to check if any of the noun phrase is a pronoun for i_NP and j_NP, should return true.